# Como selecionar os valores mínimos e máximos de uma tabela onde o mínimo seja maior que 0?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, automatização, dataset

Tenho a seguinte *Query SQL* onde retorno os valores Máximos e Mínimos da Tabela:

```
Select MAX(MyTag) As Maximo, MIN (Tag1) as Minimo from Table1
```

Porém, quero que o valor mínimo seja maior que 0, como posso arrumar essa requisição para fazer isso?

Comment: Basta usar ```nullif``` no ```MIN``` ex: ```MIN(NULLIF(Tag1,0))```

Comment: @ZéReisM.Olliver Obrigado, funcionou bem!

Answer (score -2):

Dessa maneira vai funcionar, primeiro você pega o valor do min separado e depois do max e unifica os dois.

```
--UNIFICANDO OS DOIS COM SUBSELECT

SELECT MAX(res.maximo) AS MAXIMO, MAX(res.minimo) AS MINIMO
FROM(
--MAXIMO SOZINHO

SELECT MAX(MyTag) As Maximo, 0 AS MINIMO
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

--MINIMO

SELECT 0 AS MAXIMO,  MIN(Tag1) AS MINIMO 
FROM Table1
WHERE Tag1 > 0;
) res
```

---

```
--TESTE

SELECT MAX(res.maximo) AS MAXIMO, MAX(res.minimo) AS MINIMO
FROM(
--MAXIMO SOZINHO

SELECT MAX(10) As Maximo, 0 AS MINIMO
FROM DUAL

UNION ALL

--MINIMO

SELECT 0 AS MAXIMO,  MIN(5) AS MINIMO
FROM DUAL
--WHERE Tag1 > 0;
) res
```